# .htaccess 301 redirect adds an extra slash

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

On a site that was once migrated from .asp to .php, I used the following in the .htaccess file to ensure users following old links would end up on the right page:

```
RewriteEngine On
RedirectMatch 301 (.*)\.asp$ http://www.website.org/$1.php
```

I just moved the site to a new server, where requests for .asp pages now end up with an extra slash in the address, immediately before the page name:

```
http://www.website.org//page.php
```

(How) can the above .htaccess code be tweaked to eliminate that extra slash?

Comment: I've updated my answer, it should do what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're making an assumption that `RewriteEngine On` is needed for `RedirectMatch` but it is not. `RedirectMatch` is directive of `mod_alias` and other one is from `mod_rewrite`.

You can fix your code by using **either of these two** code:

**Option 1:**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.+?)\.asp$ http://www.website.org/$1.php [L,NC,R=301]
```

**Option 2:**

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/(.+?)\.asp$ http://www.website.org/$1.php
```

You also need to make sure to test it **after clearing your browser cache** or in a new browser to avoid old browser cache.

Comment: Thanks very much for the clarification. I tried Option 2 and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
RewriteEngine On
RedirectMatch 301 ^.*/(.*)\.asp$ http://www.website.org/$1.php
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule  ^(.*)\.asp$ http://www.website.org/$1.php [NC,R=301]
```